# CSS @font-face working for one font but not another <= IE8

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I have successfully used the font face declarations for two fonts and it works for all browsers except IE8 and below.  I am using the code from http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax.  The strange thing is on IE8, one font is working and the other is not.
Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FreestyleScriptRegular';
    src: url('freescpt.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('freescpt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('freescpt.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('freescpt.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('freescpt.svg#FreestyleScriptRegular') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'GillSansMTCondensed';
    src:url(Gill_Sans_MT_Condensed.eot);/* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('Gill_Sans_MT_Condensed.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Gill_Sans_MT_Condensed.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Gill_Sans_MT_Condensed.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Gill_Sans_MT_Condensed.svg#GillSansMTCondensed') format('svg'); 

}
```

The FreestyleScriptRegular is not rendering correctly but the GillSansMTCondensed is.  I have tried everything I can think of and every hack I can think of.  I even used regenerated the eot file for the font concerned using a different application but it didn't make any difference.

Is there anything peculiar to IE8 that would prevent the second font from working?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Gill Sans MT font is protected by copyright, and use as downloadable font via `@font-face` is not permitted. Some browsers technically enforce this legal restriction.

Consider trying to find a suitable free font instead, or a font that can be licensed for a fee for the intended use.

Comment: Good to know.  The Gill Sans worked fine though but I have found a suitable free Google font to replace the freestylescript font which is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

This may be keeping your CSS from rendering properly:

```
url('freescpt.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```

There is an extra space between url('freescpt.ttf') and format(.  Try removing that and see what happens.  Don't forget to empty all caches.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply but no luck with that either. Sigh

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the code you posted, the following does not have single quotations:

```
src:url(Gill_Sans_MT_Condensed.eot);/* IE9 Compat Modes */
```

while your code here does:

```
src: url('freescpt.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
```

Try removing the quotations to make it read as such:

```
src: url(freescpt.eot); /*IE9 Compat Modes */
```

Hopefully this will help you resolve your problem.

Comment: yes, I tried that too.  I've come to the conclusion that the code is correct but the font is the issue. The fact that one font worked but the other didn't made me think the font file was the problem.  So as an alternative, I have found another Google font that is very similar and made it the fallback font in the CSS font-family declaration.  So the correct font is used in most browsers but if IE8 doesn't recognise it, it will pick up the alternative.  the only issue was the font-size changes so it did require some browser specific CSS, which is not ideal.